# Attempted to read or write protected memory error in system file task ssis package

Tags: ssis

Hi im developping an ssis package that imports excel files (.xlsx) from an ftp server to a local folder then they are imported to a sql server table . I'm using a foreach mapping to the name of files. untill here all think work fine .
i added a system file task that move (or remvove) the files from the local directory . 
this task failed , i have this error :

**Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrup**t

Comment: I assume inside your ForEach Loop container, you have a Data Flow Task and a File System Task. If you disable the Data Flow and just run the package, do you still get the memory issue?

Comment: i disable the dataFlow , i still get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

The hotfix to the .net runtime  the fix appears to be https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/923028 shall fix the issue